# How can I add intellisense for variables that don't have a constant value?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I use Nodejs on VScode for development.
I have the following code:

```
function factoryMethod({ variable }) {
    variable = variable || require('somePath.js')

    function foo() {
        variable.foo()
    }
}
```

File somePath.js:

```
module.exports = {
    foo: () => { console.log('foo') }
};
```

When I write the code **variable.foo()** I dont see the option to use function **foo** in the intellisense.
This is because I have the line of code **variable = variable || require('somePath.js')**, which means that the variable might not always have the same value.
Is there a way to force the intellisense to show me the **foo** function after writing **variable.** without changing the code and without adding comments such as JSDOC?
The reason I cannot change this code is because I have it located in many files and I cannot refactor them all.

Comment: If you use TypeScript you'll have better IntelliSense. I don't know if you can do this with plain old JS though.

Comment: you can add some JSDoc and tell that parameter `variable` is an object with a member `foo` that is a function without params

Comment: I can't change the code, since I have this problem across many files. I was hoping to change the way the intellisense works. Is this possible?